# How to simplify my system?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have created a system that has an attribute (speed) that relies on two variables, one of which is pseudo-random, and the other being highly variable and beyond the control of the user.  The pseudo-random variable I call $r$, and the highly variable attribute I call $\mu_s$.  I want to provide a graph of speed at different assumed average $\mu_s$.

The formula for speed is: $$\left[ \left(-\mu_s \cdot \ln(1-r) - A + CD\right) \ \mod \ (3 \cdot \mu_s ) \right] + A$$

$A$, $C$, and $D$ are constants defined by the user.

So, setting $\mu_s$ to some value, how may I simplify this expression and derive an expected or average speed?  I suppose what I'm really asking is, will the pseudo-random function here ($ln(1-r)$ retrieves a value from an exponential distribution) converge in such a way that I can derive an average or expected speed when $\mu_s$ is set as a constant?  Or is the function essentially random?

EDIT: Am I right in thinking that $-\mu_s \cdot ln(1-r)$ will converge to $\mu_s$?  Can I use $\mu_s$ in place of that expression to derive an 'average' speed?

Comment: You can also generate the exponential random variable with $- \mathrm{ln} (r)$ because $r$ and $1-r$ are identically distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected value of your exponential random variable is 1. So, if $\mu_s$ is regarded as a constant, the average speed will be $\left[(\mu_s - A + CD ) \ \mathrm{mod} (3\mu_s)\right] + A.$

I wouldn't say it converges. In the language of random variables it is an expected value, or as you say, an average.